Can you grapple a creature as an Opportunity Attack?
Under the 2014 rules, it was accepted that you could not grapple as an Opportunity Attack.
Now, with the 2024 rules: Can you grapple a creature as an Opportunity Attack?

Yes
An Opportunity Attack states (emphasis mine):

Opportunity Attacks
You can make an Opportunity Attack when a creature
that you can see leaves your reach using its action, its Bonus Action,
its Reaction, or one of its speeds. To make the Opportunity Attack,
take a Reaction to make one melee attack with a weapon or an Unarmed
Strike against the provoking creature. The attack occurs right before
the creature leaves your reach.

And Damage, Grapple, and Shove are considered Unarmed Strikes:

Unarmed Strike
[...] In game
terms, this is an Unarmed Strike—a melee attack that involves you
using your body to damage, grapple, or shove a target within 5 feet of
you.
Whenever you use your Unarmed Strike, choose one of the following
options for its effect.
Damage. You make an attack roll against the target. [...]
Grapple. The target must succeed on a Strength or Dexterity saving throw (it chooses which), or it has the Grappled condition. [...]
Shove. The target must succeed on a Strength or Dexterity saving throw (it chooses which), or you either push it 5 feet away or cause it to have the Prone condition. [...]


Did WotC learn nothing!? In PF2e it's specifically REALLY HARD to get a Trip on reaction, because chain-tripping is so very powerful. And 5e2024 just gives it to everyone!?

@PaulZ: And this somewhat diminished the value of the Sentinel feat, although that just requires you to hit their AC instead of having them save against your DC, so can work against very strong monsters.  (Fun fact: Sentinel was buffed in 2024; now the reaction you take when they hit someone other than you is also an op attack and sets their speed to 0, so you don't have to save your reaction if you think they might be about to leave after attacking.  And it works even if creature being attacked also has sentinel.)

@PaulZ, you're going to be really upset when you realize that the Topple weapon mastery can accomplish this, alongside d10+ damage from reach weapons...
